# Viewing history of conda transactions?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Is there a way of viewing past conda transactions? For instance, a history of all `conda install` actions I did in the current environment would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Does something like reverse-i-search work for you? : As mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/how-to-cycle-through-reverse-i-search-in-bash . Or do we need past conda commands for an environment by timestamps?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is a [`--revisions, -r`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html#Named%20Arguments) flag for this.

```
conda list --revisions
```

Check the `conda list --help` for more info.

If you'd like an exact history, there is a `conda-meta/history` log in every environment.  You could, for example, pull out every command ever executed in an environment, plus a timestamp, using

```
grep -B1 "^# cmd" ${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta/history
```

Comment: While each revision lists the result of a specific command, but is it possible to get the command itself of that revision?

Comment: @VimNing That’s exactly what the grep does.

Comment: Thank you! Just a notice to let you know your answer made my day!

Answer (score 8):

When you use the "my_env/conda-meta/history", it shows the exact cmd as well that as been used for the successive revisions and it shows the date as well.

For example, following is the snippet of the my_env/conda-meta/history

```
==> 2020-04-08 03:47:11 <==
# cmd: /home/calvin/anaconda3/bin/conda update -c nilmtk nilmtk
# conda version: 4.8.3
```

Comment: Can you put also an example of "my_env"?

Comment: @Student.py the example could be something like: `/home/<userName>/programs/anaconda3/envs/sphinx/conda-meta`, where `sphinx` is the name of my enviroment. Then the `history` file is basically a text file without suffix, thus you can view it in unix's shell e.g. like this `less history`