# ResolvePackageNotFound error in creating anaconda environment with yml

Tags: python, anaconda, centos7, cartopy

I created an environment on my local computer with Anaconda. After that, I created yml file for the environment with `conda env export > environment.yml`. I tried creating the same environment with yml file on CentOS server by `conda env create -f environment.yml`. Then I got the following error:

```
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .............

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - cartopy 0.17.0 py36h95120c7_1006
```

I did some googling and tried moving the line under `pip` but then similar error popped up for different library. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like that's an OS X build and you're transitioning to Linux. Technically, [Conda envs are not inherently cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015738/570918), however, you can try adding the `--no-builds` flag, or the `--from-history` flag to your `conda env export` command to get less platform-specific output from the export.

Comment: Indeed you are correct that I'm transitioning from macOS to Linux. `--from-history` solved this issue. Thanks a lot!