# Specific package build is not available

Tags: python, installation, package, conda

I am having trouble installing packages with Conda when providing a specific build. For example,

```
conda install wrapt==1.10.11=py35h14c3975_2
```

yields

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - wrapt==1.10.11=py35h14c3975_2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

but if I run just

```
conda install wrapt
```

it offers me a package in another build

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  wrapt              pkgs/main/win-64::wrapt-1.10.11-py35hfa6e2cd_2
```

So my questions are, why can't Conda install this specific build of a package and how could I circumvent it?

Answer (score 1):

### Wrong Platform

Unlike versions, builds are often platform-specific. That particular build is from [the **main**/**anaconda** channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/wrapt/files?version=1.10.11) under the **linux-64** subdirectory. You cannot install that on a Windows system (as indicated by the channels output) because it likely includes compiled code that cannot run on that architecture.

There are directions in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39280638/570918) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015738/570918) about generating package and environment specifications that work across platforms, though this is not something Conda guarantees.