# Is listing specific versions in a conda environment.yml file dangerous for env reproducibility?

Tags: package, conda, channel

I am a novice Conda user (~1 year of using; mostly Miniconda, FWIW) and I have occasionally run into issues trying to create a Conda environment (env) from a YAML file, seemingly because of specific file versions being listed. Does specifying specific versions as well as channels in a YAML make an environment less likely to solve in the future? Specifically, do channels that contain a specific version at the time of creating a YAML file ever wipe those versions from their package listing in the future?

**Command:**

```bash
conda env create -f snap.yml
```

**Stdout:**

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- markupsafe==1.1.1=py36h68aa20f_3
- ipykernel==5.5.0=py36h7b2dad6_1
- vc==14.2=h21ff451_1
- tornado==6.1=py36h68aa20f_1
- pip==21.0.1=py36haa95532_0
- mistune==0.8.4=py36h68aa20f_1003
- zeromq==4.3.3=h0e60522_3
- vs2015_runtime==14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
- m2w64-gcc-libs==5.3.0=7
- winpty==0.4.3=4
- m2w64-gcc-libgfortran==5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-libs-core==5.3.0=7
- pandoc==2.11.4=h8ffe710_0
- libsodium==1.0.18=h8d14728_1
- pyzmq==22.0.3=py36hb0157bd_0
- msys2-conda-epoch==20160418=1
- jupyter_core==4.7.1=py36ha15d459_0
- wincertstore==0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
- pywinpty==0.5.7=py36h9f0ad1d_1
- python==3.6.3=h3b118a2_4
- cffi==1.14.5=py36he58ceb7_0
- m2w64-libwinpthread-git==5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
- terminado==0.9.2=py36ha15d459_0
- pyrsistent==0.17.3=py36h68aa20f_2
- certifi==2020.12.5=py36ha15d459_1
- m2w64-gmp==6.1.0=2
- pywin32==300=py36h68aa20f_0
- setuptools==52.0.0=py36haa95532_0
- importlib-metadata==3.7.0=py36ha15d459_0
- notebook==6.2.0=py36ha15d459_0
- nbconvert==6.0.7=py36ha15d459_3
- argon2-cffi==20.1.0=py36h68aa20f_2
```

**Contents of snap.yml:**

```yaml
name: snap
channels:

- conda-forge
- defaults
  dependencies:
- argon2-cffi=20.1.0=py36h68aa20f_2
- async_generator=1.10=py_0
- attrs=20.3.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
- backports=1.0=py_2
- backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.1=py_0
- bleach=3.3.0=pyh44b312d_0
- certifi=2020.12.5=py36ha15d459_1
- cffi=1.14.5=py36he58ceb7_0
- colorama=0.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- decorator=4.4.2=py_0
- defusedxml=0.6.0=py_0
- entrypoints=0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1003
- importlib-metadata=3.7.0=py36ha15d459_0
- importlib_metadata=3.7.0=hd8ed1ab_0
- ipykernel=5.5.0=py36h7b2dad6_1
- ipython=5.8.0=py36_1
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
- jinja2=2.11.3=pyh44b312d_0
- jsonschema=3.2.0=py_2
- jupyter_client=6.1.11=pyhd8ed1ab_1
- jupyter_core=4.7.1=py36ha15d459_0
- jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- libsodium=1.0.18=h8d14728_1
- m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
- m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
- markupsafe=1.1.1=py36h68aa20f_3
- mistune=0.8.4=py36h68aa20f_1003
- msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
- nbclient=0.5.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- nbconvert=6.0.7=py36ha15d459_3
- nbformat=5.1.2
- nest-asyncio=1.4.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- notebook=6.2.0=py36ha15d459_0
- packaging=20.9=pyh44b312d_0
- pandoc=2.11.4=h8ffe710_0
- pandocfilters=1.4.2=py_1
- pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
- pip=21.0.1=py36haa95532_0
- prometheus_client=0.9.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py_1
- pycparser=2.20=pyh9f0ad1d_2
- pygments=2.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- pyparsing=2.4.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- pyrsistent=0.17.3=py36h68aa20f_2
- python=3.6.3=h3b118a2_4
- python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
- python_abi=3.6=1_cp36m
- pywin32=300=py36h68aa20f_0
- pywinpty=0.5.7=py36h9f0ad1d_1
- pyzmq=22.0.3=py36hb0157bd_0
- send2trash=1.5.0=py_0
- setuptools=52.0.0=py36haa95532_0
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py_1
- six=1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- terminado=0.9.2=py36ha15d459_0
- testpath=0.4.4=py_0
- tornado=6.1=py36h68aa20f_1
- traitlets=4.3.3=py36h9f0ad1d_1
- typing_extensions=3.7.4.3=py_0
- vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
- vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
- wcwidth=0.2.5=pyh9f0ad1d_2
- webencodings=0.5.1=py_1
- wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
- wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
- winpty=0.4.3=4
- zeromq=4.3.3=h0e60522_3
- zipp=3.4.0=py_0
- pip:
  - absl-py==0.11.0
  - apricot-select==0.5.0
  - astor==0.8.1
  - cached-property==1.5.2
  - chardet==3.0.4
  - cleverhans==3.0.1
  - cloudpickle==1.6.0
  - common==0.1.2
  - cycler==0.10.0
  - efficientnet==1.0.0
  - future==0.18.2
  - gast==0.2.2
  - google-pasta==0.2.0
  - grpcio==1.36.0
  - h5py==2.10.0
  - hypothesis==5.5.4
  - idna==2.10
  - image-classifiers==1.0.0
  - imageio==2.9.0
  - joblib==1.0.1
  - keras==2.2.4
  - keras-applications==1.0.8
  - keras-preprocessing==1.1.2
  - keras-resnet==0.2.0
  - keras-unet==0.0.7
  - kiwisolver==1.3.1
  - llvmlite==0.35.0
  - markdown==3.3.4
  - matplotlib==3.3.4
  - mnist==0.2.2
  - networkx==2.5
  - nose==1.3.7
  - numba==0.52.0
  - numpy==1.19.5
  - opencv-python==4.2.0.32
  - opt-einsum==3.3.0
  - pandas==1.1.5
  - pillow==8.1.0
  - progressbar2==3.53.1
  - protobuf==3.15.3
  - pycodestyle==2.6.0
  - pydot==1.4.1
  - python-utils==2.3.0
  - pytz==2021.1
  - pywavelets==1.1.1
  - pyyaml==5.4.1
  - requests==2.23.0
  - scikit-image==0.16.2
  - scikit-learn==0.22.2
  - scipy==1.5.4
  - segmentation-models==1.0.1
  - sortedcontainers==2.3.0
  - tensorboard==1.15.0
  - tensorflow==1.15.2
  - tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
  - tensorflow-probability==0.9.0
  - termcolor==1.1.0
  - tf-explain==0.2.1
  - tqdm==4.58.0
  - urllib3==1.25.11
  - werkzeug==1.0.1
  - wrapt==1.12.1
    prefix: C:\\Users\\zaki.conda\\envs\\snap
```

Upon reviewing similar questions, I also tried removing the suffixes after the second "=". This shortened the list quite a bit, but resulted in some packages still being listed:

```bash
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- winpty=0.4.3
- m2w64-gmp=6.1.0
- m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0
- vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016
- vc=14.2
- pywinpty=0.5.7
- m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757
- pywin32=300
- m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0
- msys2-conda-epoch=20160418
- m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0
```

---

**EDIT:** Okay I'm pretty sure this is just because this package wasn't made to work on linux, because all the missing packages seem windows-related. I'll wait to delete this post in case anyone is willing to expand on some of the original broader questions, even though this case is essentially solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

The example YAML captures both versions and builds, which improves reproducibility *on that specific platform* (**win-64** in this case). That is, it gives extra information to identify exactly which binary builds of packages were installed in the environment.

However, build information is specific to the platform, and so including it in the YAML can constrain the environment from being used across different platforms. Moreover, platforms often require specific supporting packages that are not available on other platforms. So, even leaving out builds and versions can still result in a YAML that is not **portable** across platforms.

The following questions have related information:

- [conda fails to create environment from yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554431/conda-fails-to-create-environment-from-yml)
- [How to share conda environments across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39280638/570918)
- [Managing conda env in cross platform environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58009732/570918)

---

### Reproducible Workflows

> **Recommendation:** Do not rely on `conda env export`!

For anyone aiming to produce *portable* and *reusable* environment definitions, consider adopting a **YAML-first workflow**:

- manually maintain a user-generated YAML file
- only include end requirements
- use only `conda env create` and `conda env update` commands to modify the environment instance.

An even better solution these days is [`conda-lock`](https://conda.github.io/conda-lock/) lockfiles. The lockfiles from `conda-lock` define *solved* enviornments, directly specify URLs to package tarballs, and support multiple platforms in a single file.