# Get previous package versions with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda, python-venv

Given a specific package name when I run

`conda list my-package-name`

I get its current version. What's a simple way / command to get instead the history of the package versions I've installed in the current environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Not for a specific package at a time, but there are [ways to look at all transaction history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56069934/570918). A variation on that advice would be to filter the revision output with grep. For example, looking at the `mamba` package in my **base** repository:

```
PKG_OF_INTEREST="mamba"
conda list -n base --revisions | grep -E "\s${PKG_OF_INTEREST}\s"
     mamba  {0.7.6 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.7.14 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.7.14 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.11.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.11.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.13.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.13.0 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.13.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.13.0 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.14.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.14.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.15.2 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.15.2 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.15.3 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.15.3 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.16.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.16.0 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.18.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.18.0 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.18.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.18.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.17.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.17.0 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.19.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.19.0 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.19.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.19.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.19.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.19.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.21.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.21.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.22.1 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
     mamba  {0.22.1 (conda-forge/osx-64) -> 0.23.0 (conda-forge/osx-64)}
```