# Conda: Why is environment stuck with blas 1.0

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Conda has yet another variant of the `blas`, `mkl`, et al. dance in stock for me, that I was unaware of, which I cannot resolve, and on which I would appreciate your help. I.e. usually, upon `conda update --all` and once in a while my  `blas, x.y, mkl, conda-forge` got upgraded to some version `x1.y1` higher then the previous. But since approximately a month ago my `blas` got downgraded to version `1.0`

```
(py) ~>conda list | grep mkl
blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
```

and ever since then it remains stuck there, even if at least at the time of writing

```
(py) ~>conda search -f blas | grep mkl
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
blas                            2.21             mkl  conda-forge
```

Is there a way to find out why, which package, or whatever keeps me at `1.0` even if at least `2.21` is available?

Comment: Maybe check Conda's logs to see what's happened at those rollbacks? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069924/viewing-history-of-conda-transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `mamba repoquery`

One of the extra commands that Mamba adds over Conda is the `repoquery` tool. Namely, the `whoneeds` subcommand will identify packages that has a `blas` requirement listed in the metadata.

### Example

Here is an example from an older environment I have sitting around, that happens to have `blas=1.0=mkl` installed.

```bash
## activate the environment
$ mamba activate umap

## query for depending packages
(umap) $ mamba repoquery whoneeds blas
# ...
Executing the query blas

 Name         Version Build          Depends      Channel  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 scikit-learn 0.20.3  py37h27c97d8_0 blas 1.0 mkl pkgs/main
 mkl_random   1.0.2   py37h27c97d8_0 blas 1.0 mkl pkgs/main
 numpy        1.16.2  py37hacdab7b_0 blas 1.0 mkl pkgs/main
 numpy-base   1.16.2  py37h6575580_0 blas 1.0 mkl pkgs/main
 mkl_fft      1.0.10  py37h5e564d8_0 blas 1.0 mkl pkgs/main
 scipy        1.2.1   py37h1410ff5_0 blas 1.0 mkl pkgs/main
```

However, to determine some chain of blame, we probably need to look at the explicit specifications in the environment. For this environment, it is kind of trivial:

```
## the `--from-history` flag will show only explicit specifications
$ mamba env export -n umap --from-history
name: umap
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - umap-learn
```

That is, there is only one specified package in this environment, and it wasn't in the list. It might be additionally helpful to view the depending packages as a tree:

```bash
(umap) $ mamba repoquery whoneeds --tree blas
# ...
Executing the query blas

blas[1.0]
  ├─ scikit-learn[0.20.3]
  │  └─ umap-learn[0.3.8]
  ├─ mkl_random[1.0.2]
  │  └─ numpy[1.16.2]
  │     ├─ scikit-learn already visited
  │     ├─ numba[0.43.1]
  │     │  └─ umap-learn already visited
  │     ├─ mkl_fft[1.0.10]
  │     ├─ scipy[1.2.1]
  │     │  ├─ scikit-learn already visited
  │     │  └─ umap-learn already visited
  │     └─ umap-learn already visited
  ├─ numpy already visited
  ├─ numpy-base[1.16.2]
  │  ├─ mkl_random already visited
  │  └─ numpy already visited
  ├─ mkl_fft already visited
  └─ scipy already visited
```

Here, we see how `umap-learn` is connected to the chain of packages that are directly specifying `blas=1.0`. In this case, I probably could just run  `mamba update umap-learn` and it would move on. I.e., it's not stuck like in OP.

## Dry-run newer version

A less forensic approach would be to try letting Conda/Mamba blame a package. This is not always reliable, but sometimes it works. [Conda is particularly bad at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/570918), so I'd try Mamba:

```
## try installing a newer blas, but use `-d` for dry-run
mamba install -n py -d 'blas >1'
```

In the best case, it will report a package that is conflicting with this request.

Comment: Before I give `mamba`  - which looks like a whole new package manager - a try, would `conda-tree` provide me with somehow similar functionality?

Comment: Sure. Mamba's `repoquery` is a C++ implementation of that `conda-tree` functionality. I wouldn't characterize Mamba as "a whole new package manager". It's a compiled (fast) version of Conda. It still manages Conda environments and uses `.condarc` settings etc. The only change after installing is using the command `mamba` instead of `conda`, and you save yourself time and CPU cycles.